# get the name of a runnable jar file

Tags: java, jar

Hello so I have made an Jar updater and it is working perfect the only issue i am having is that if the client is named different it will download it as a separate jar file and not replace the one you are running so this is where i get my client location and name

```
private static String myClient = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator  + "Trinity.jar";
```

Now i was wondering how do i get the name of the jar that has been ran on startup so  i can use it to replace the old jar file correctly

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189162/get-name-of-running-jar-or-exe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Comment: I tired this before it was not doing anything for me sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java provides **MyClass** which contains all the attributes of the current class's context which includes runtime information. Using the right combination utility functions can yield you the required path.

```
Path = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
```

Comment: I was being a retard lol i was testing it in eclipse so it was just getting the main class file name lol

Comment: Haha , happens to the best of us :D